# SonarQube history not updating

Tags: sonarqube

We are using SonarQube in version 6.3.1 and it works nicely.

However at May 10th in one of our projects the history graph ends, see screenshot. There were no errors in the logs and analysis is working fine. Just the history is no longer continued. On one other project, the history ends at already end of march, other project are still doing fine.

Any idea how to narrow down on what might be the root cause of this issue?

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Did you run other analysis of your project since those dates ? did the project key changed (so the new analysis are under that new project) ? This last one can happen if you run maven analysis and change group id for instance.

Comment: Hi benzonico. Thanks for your answer. As already mentioned above, the analysis itself is working fine. We run it 5 times a day. Project name nor key were changed. Any other idea?

Comment: Hi @benzonico . Any new idea concerning our issue? It is still present and we really would like to get it fixed. Thanks in advance.